# Multiple Authentication for API Gateway Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, api-key

I want to Authorize the request to API Gateway using COGNITO_USER_POOLS or API Key, That is the incoming request can have either of authentication token(using COGNITO_USER_POOLS) or API Key

Is there anyway to configure both types of authorization and use either of one of them to authenticate on a single API Gateway resource?